# Not able to call another controller in one controller in angular using $rootScope,$compile and $route

Tags: angularjs, controller, rootscope

```
 mainApp
 .controller('homeController',
   function($scope, $http, $timeout, $compile, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $route) {
      //code goes here
   }
);

 mainApp.controller('ReportsController',
    function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
       //another controller code goes here
    }
);
```

I am going to call the homeController in reportsController on reload of the reportsController page, How can I call that ?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers in angularjs are not meant to be used in each other. for those kind of functionalities, wrap all common codes you need in a factory or service (services are singletons and live across the application) and inject the service into both controller.

Answer (score 0):

Got The Answer:

add the dependency in apprun.js

$location
and then

```
mainApp.run(function($rootScope, $rootScope, $window,$location){

$location.path('/');
});
```